# Prove that $\int_0^t M_sdM_s=\frac 12 (M_t^2 - \langle M \rangle _t)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

> Let $M$ martingale limited, continuous, integrable with a square. Prove that $$\int_0^t M_sdM_s=\frac 12 (M_t^2 - \langle M \rangle _t)$$

This theorem is proven on the forum and in many books but for Brownian motion. Unfortunately, I don't know how to prove it in the general case - for a martingale with the given in task properties.

Important note - Ito's formula has not yet been derived during the lecture, so we are not allowed to use it.

Comment: For continuous (semi)martingales $X$ and $Y$ and a partition $0=t^n_1<\cdots<t^n_{p_n}=t$ whose mesh vanishes as $n$ goes to $+\infty$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{p_n}(X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}})^2\overset{\mathbb P}{\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}}\langle X\rangle_t\quad\textrm{and}\quad\sum_{k=1}^{p_n}X_{t_{k-1}}(Y_{t_k}-Y_{t_{k-1}})\overset{\mathbb P}{\underset{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}}\int_0^tX_s\,dY_s.
$$ Play with that.